# MITライセンスの派生物に対しての著作権表示の書き方が分からない

Tags: ライセンス, mit-license

ここでは、自分も相手も「MITライセンス」でOSSを作っていると仮定します。

MITライセンスは著作権表示さえすれば、改変等が許可されているライセンスですが、その書き方がいまいち分かりません。

ChatGPTで調べたところ、以下のように "and" を使えと言われたのですが、この書き方は正しいでしょうか？

```
MIT License

Copyright (c) 2023 [自分の名前] and [新しい著作権者の名前]

内容
```

また、その人のGitHubのリポジトリのURLなどは書かなくてよろしいのでしょうか？

Comment: 「コピペ」だといまいち意図が伝わらない可能性がある、印象が悪い場合があるので、「派生物」としておきました。 / "その人のGitHubのリポジトリ" は、元の作者 or 派生物の作者 (=あなた) のどちらを指していますか？

Comment: 修正していただき、ありがとうございます